# Custom UI library not working in project

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have added a library in my project. However, when I use any of the views provided by the library, it gives me `unbound prefix error`. I have added the **namespace** as well in my xml file, still I am getting this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:wingokuFlatUI="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >


     <com.wingoku.flatUI.WinGokuFlatButton

        android:id="@+id/wingoku3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wingoku"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        wingokuFlatUI:normalStateColor="#EB974E"
        wingokuFlatUI:pressedStateColor="#F2784B" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

After making some changes, now I am getting this error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'normalStateColor' in package 
     'com.example.android_flatui_testing'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'pressedStateColor' in package 
     'com.example.android_flatui_testing'
```

What changes can I make to the code in order to get rid of this error?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The namespace you are defining is `flatUI` and you are using `flatui` later. I think you should be using the same character casing in both the instances.

Comment: still not working. Can you please review the code on github? I think I have done something wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [website](http://www.wingoku.com/2014/04/wingoku-flatui-ui-theming-library-for.html) for this before...

they implemented an example for adding the xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:wingokuFlatButton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wingoku.flatUI"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
```

Comment: yes silly me. Now when I run the project, I am getting view inflation exception. ClassNotFound error